# JavaScript and HTML form validation

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to do a simple validation on a button, but when I click the button without entering anything it still goes to testValidation1.html instead of popping up the alert window.

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

      <form action="testValidation1.html">

         Parameter1 : 
          <input type = 'text' name = 'param1'/><br>

          <input type='submit' value = 'submit' onclick = 'return validateForm()'>
      </form>

      <script type="text/javascript">

      function validateForm() {
             var f1 = document.forms[0];
             var p1 = f1.param1;

             if(p1.value.length == 0) {

                alert('Plz enter parameters');
                p1.focus();
                return false;
             }  
     }

      </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I might be dumb, but should it perhaps be `onclick = 'validateForm()'` instead of `onclick = 'return validateForm()'`?

Comment: Try `onsubmit` instead (within `<form>` tag).

Comment: I test it in my localhost .. it works fine .. it always show the popup ..

Comment: @IbrahimAsad, sometimes it shows the alert window but as soon as I clicked ok button it redirects me to testValidate1 page which it shouldn't right.

Comment: It should Never redirect to the other page ... 
I test it with IE,chrome , Firefox .. 
and every time it show the popup to me .
:)

Comment: @IbrahimAsad, I don't know whatz wrong actually I tried it on JSFiddle and it worked nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might find it easier to use the submit event of the form to validate

```
function validateForm(event) {
    var form = this;
    var p1 = form.elements['param1'];
    if(p1.value.length === 0) {
        alert('Plz enter parameters');
        p1.focus();
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}

document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', validateForm);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7j0usuam/